# Manual split versus Scikit Grid Search

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am perplexed by achieving seemingly very different results when relying on a "manual" split of the data between training and test sets and using the scikit-learn grid search function. I am using an evaluation function sourced from a kaggle competition for both runs and the grid search is over a single value (the same value as the manual split). The resulting gini value is so different there has to be an error somewhere but I dont see it and am wondering if there is an oversight I am making in the comparison?

The first code block when ran for me results in gini of just "`Validation Sample Score: 0.0033997889 (normalized gini).`"

The second block (using scikit) results in much higher values:

```
Fitting 2 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 2 fits
0.334467621189
0.339421569449
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   2 | elapsed:  9.9min remaining:  -198.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:  9.9min finished
{'n_estimators': 1000}
0.336944643888
[mean: 0.33694, std: 0.00248, params: {'n_estimators': 1000}]
```

**Eval function:**

```
def gini(solution, submission):
    df = zip(solution, submission)
    df = sorted(df, key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)
    rand = [float(i+1)/float(len(df)) for i in range(len(df))]
    totalPos = float(sum([x[0] for x in df]))
    cumPosFound = [df[0][0]]
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        cumPosFound.append(cumPosFound[len(cumPosFound)-1] + df[i][0])
    Lorentz = [float(x)/totalPos for x in cumPosFound]
    Gini = [Lorentz[i]-rand[i] for i in range(len(df))]
    return sum(Gini)

def normalized_gini(solution, submission):
    normalized_gini = gini(solution, submission)/gini(solution, solution)
    print normalized_gini
    return normalized_gini


gini_scorer = metrics.make_scorer(normalized_gini, greater_is_better = True)
```

**Block 1:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    dat=pd.read_table('train.csv',sep=",")

    y=dat[['Hazard']].values.ravel()
    dat=dat.drop(['Hazard','Id'],axis=1)

    #sample out 30% for validation
    folds=train_test_split(range(len(y)),test_size=0.3) #30% test
    train_X=dat.iloc[folds[0],:]
    train_y=y[folds[0]]
    test_X=dat.iloc[folds[1],:]
    test_y=y[folds[1]]


    #assume no leakage by OH whole data
    dat_dict=train_X.T.to_dict().values()
    vectorizer = DV( sparse = False )
    vectorizer.fit( dat_dict )
    train_X = vectorizer.transform( dat_dict )

    del dat_dict

    dat_dict=test_X.T.to_dict().values()
    test_X = vectorizer.transform( dat_dict )

    del dat_dict



    rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=-1)
    rf.fit(train_X,train_y)
    y_submission=rf.predict(test_X)
    print "Validation Sample Score: %.10f (normalized gini)." % normalized_gini(test_y,y_submission)
```

**Block 2:**

```
dat_dict=dat.T.to_dict().values()
vectorizer = DV( sparse = False )
vectorizer.fit( dat_dict )
X = vectorizer.transform( dat_dict )

parameters= {'n_estimators': [1000]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), param_grid=parameters,cv=2, verbose=1, scoring=gini_scorer,n_jobs=-1)
grid_search.fit(X,y)

print grid_search.best_params_
print grid_search.best_score_
print grid_search.grid_scores_
```

**EDIT**

Here is a self contained example where I am getting the same sort of difference.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold, KFold, ShuffleSplit,train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor , ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer as DV
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV,RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor
from scipy.stats import randint, uniform
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston




if __name__ == '__main__':

    b=load_boston()
    X = pd.DataFrame(b.data)
    y = b.target

    #sample out 30% for validation
    folds=train_test_split(range(len(y)),test_size=0.5) #50% test
    train_X=X.iloc[folds[0],:]
    train_y=y[folds[0]]
    test_X=X.iloc[folds[1],:]
    test_y=y[folds[1]]


    rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=-1)
    rf.fit(train_X,train_y)
    y_submission=rf.predict(test_X)

    print "Validation Sample Score: %.10f (mean squared)." % mean_squared_error(test_y,y_submission)


    parameters= {'n_estimators': [1000]}
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), param_grid=parameters,cv=2, verbose=1, scoring='mean_squared_error',n_jobs=-1)
    grid_search.fit(X,y)

    print grid_search.best_params_
    print grid_search.best_score_
    print grid_search.grid_scores_
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I can provide you with a complete solution but here are some pointers:

1. Use **random_state** parameter of scikit-learn objects when debugging this kind of issue as it makes your results *really* reproducible.
   The following will always return exactly the same number:

   ```
   rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=-1, random_state=0)
   rf.fit(train_X,train_y)
   y_submission=rf.predict(test_X)
   mean_squared_error(test_y,y_submission)
   ```

It resets the random number generator to make sure that you always get "the same randomness". You should be using it on `train_test_split` and `GridSearchCV` too.

2. The results you get on the self-contained example are normal. Typically I got:

   ```
   Validation Sample Score: 9.8136434847 (mean squared).
   [mean: -22.38918, std: 11.56372, params: {'n_estimators': 1000}]
   ```

First, note that the mean squared error returned from `GridSearchCV` is a **negated mean squared error**. I think this is by design to keep the spirit of a score function (for a score, greater is better).

Now this is still 9.81 against 22.38. However here the standard deviation is HUGE. It can explain that the scores look so different.
If you want to check that `GridSearchCV` is not doing something dubious you can force it to use one split only, and the same as your manual split:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold, KFold, ShuffleSplit,train_test_split, PredefinedSplit
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor , ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer as DV
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV,RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor
from scipy.stats import randint, uniform
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b=load_boston()
    X = pd.DataFrame(b.data)
    y = b.target
    folds=train_test_split(range(len(y)),test_size=0.5, random_state=15) #50% test
    folds_split = np.ones_like(y)
    folds_split[folds[0]] = -1
    ps = PredefinedSplit(folds_split)

    for tr, te in ps:
        train_X=X.iloc[tr,:]
        train_y=y[tr]
        test_X=X.iloc[te,:]
        test_y=y[te]
        rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=1, random_state=15)
        rf.fit(train_X,train_y)
        y_submission=rf.predict(test_X)
        print("Validation Sample Score: {:.10f} (mean squared).".format(mean_squared_error(test_y, y_submission)))

    parameters= {'n_estimators': [1000], 'n_jobs': [1], 'random_state': [15]}
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), param_grid=parameters,cv=ps, verbose=2, scoring='mean_squared_error', n_jobs=1)
    grid_search.fit(X,y)

    print("best_params: ", grid_search.best_params_)
    print("best_score", grid_search.best_score_)
    print("grid_scores", grid_search.grid_scores_)
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Sorry I can't figure out what's going on with your Gini scorer. I'd say 0.0033xxx seems like a very low value though (almost no model at all?) for a normalized gini score.

Comment: Thank you for some hints. I have determined the issue to be when in the process the one-hot encoding is done. I started a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506987/scikit-learn-one-hot-encode-before-or-after-train-test-split

Answer (score 5):

Following your minimal example and response from user3914041 and Andreus, this works as intended. Indeed, I got :

```
Validation Sample Score: 10.176958 (mean squared).
Fitting 1 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 1 fits
mean: 10.19074, std: 0.00000, params: {'n_estimators': 1000}
```

In this case we have the same result in both methodologies (omitting some rounding). Here is the code to reproduce the same scores:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, PredefinedSplit
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

b=load_boston()
X = b.data
y = b.target

folds=train_test_split(range(len(y)),test_size=0.5, random_state=10)
train_X=X[folds[0],:]
train_y=y[folds[0]]
test_X=X[folds[1],:]
test_y=y[folds[1]]

folds_split = np.zeros_like(y)
folds_split[folds[0]] = -1
ps = PredefinedSplit(folds_split)

rf=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, random_state=42)
rf.fit(train_X,train_y)
y_submission=rf.predict(test_X)

print "Validation Sample Score: %f (mean squared)." % mean_squared_error(test_y,y_submission)

mse_scorer = make_scorer(mean_squared_error)
parameters= {'n_estimators': [1000]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42), cv=ps,
                           param_grid=parameters, verbose=1, scoring=mse_scorer)
grid_search.fit(X,y)

print grid_search.grid_scores_[0]
```

In your first example, try to remove `greater_is_better=True`. Indeed, the Gini coefficient is supposed to be minimized, not maximized.

Try to see if this solves the problem. You can also add some random seed to ensure your split are done in the exact same fashion.

Answer (score 4):

There is one difference between the two blocks of code, that I can tell. By using `cv=2`, you are splitting the data into two 50% sized chunks. Then the resulting gini is averaged between them.

As a side note, are you sure you want `greater_is_better=True` in your scorer? From your post, you imply that you want to lower that score. Be super careful on that point, as GridSearchCV maximizes score.

From the [GridSearchCV documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV):

> The parameters selected are those that maximize the score of the left out data, unless an explicit score is passed in which case it is used instead.

Comment: It cant be due to the 50/50 split the mean and the standard error of the CV clearly are not close in magnitude to the result I get with the manual split. That said...I have no idea what the issue is. I also changed to use the built in mean_squared_error scorer and had the same very different result.

Comment: I added a self contained example. I am still getting this different result.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is quite old now, so I assume y'all've figured this out, but for clarity, there were at least 3 issues in the original 2 blocks that caused them to yield different results: in short, a failure to set a couple random seeds and a failure to use PredefinedSplit on the folds returned by train_test_split (the iteration over which can end up re-ordering the splits).  Here is stand-alone code to illustrate, using a different gini implementation:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, PredefinedSplit
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer as DV
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn import metrics

def gini(expected, predicted):
    assert expected.shape[0] == predicted.shape[0], 'unequal number of rows: [ %d vs %d ]' \
        % ( expected.shape[0] == predicted.shape[0] )

    _all = np.asarray(np.c_[
        expected,
        predicted,
        np.arange(expected.shape[0])], dtype=np.float)

    _EXPECTED = 0
    _PREDICTED = 1
    _INDEX = 2

    # sort by predicted descending, then by index ascending
    sort_order = np.lexsort((_all[:, _INDEX], -1 * _all[:, _PREDICTED]))
    _all = _all[sort_order]

    total_losses = _all[:, _EXPECTED].sum()
    gini_sum = _all[:, _EXPECTED].cumsum().sum() / total_losses
    gini_sum -= (expected.shape[0] + 1.0) / 2.0
    return gini_sum / expected.shape[0]

def gini_normalized(solution, submission, gini=gini):
    solution = np.array(solution)
    submission = np.array(submission)
    return gini(solution, submission) / gini(solution, solution)


gini_scorer = metrics.make_scorer( gini_normalized, greater_is_better=True )


dat=pd.read_table('train.csv',sep=',')
y=dat[['Hazard']].values.ravel()
dat=dat.drop(['Hazard','Id'],axis=1)

# 1. set seed for train_test_split()
folds = train_test_split( range(len(y)), test_size=0.7, random_state=15 ) # 70% test

dat_dict=dat.T.to_dict().values()
vectorizer=DV( sparse = False )
vectorizer.fit( dat_dict )
dat=vectorizer.transform( dat_dict )
dat=pd.DataFrame(dat)


# 2. instead of using the raw folds returned by train_test_split,
#   use the PredefinedSplit iterator, just like GridSearchCV does
if 0:
    train_X=dat.iloc[folds[0]]
    train_y=y[folds[0]]
    test_X=dat.iloc[folds[1]]
    test_y=y[folds[1]]
else:
    folds_split = np.zeros_like(y)
    folds_split[folds[0]] = -1
    ps = PredefinedSplit(folds_split)

    # in this example, there's only one iteration here
    for train_index, test_index in ps:
        train_X, test_X = dat.iloc[train_index], dat.iloc[test_index]
        train_y, test_y = y[train_index], y[test_index]


n_estimators = [ 100, 200 ]

# 3. also set seed for RFR
rfr_params = { 'n_jobs':7, 'random_state':15 }


######################################################################
# manual grid search ( block 1 )

for n_est in n_estimators:

    print 'n_estimators = %d:' % n_est; sys.stdout.flush()

    rfr = RandomForestRegressor( n_estimators=n_est, **rfr_params )
    rfr.fit( train_X, train_y )
    y_pred = rfr.predict( test_X )

    gscore = gini_normalized( test_y, y_pred )

    print ' validation score: %.5f (normalized gini)' % gscore


######################################################################
# GridSearchCV grid search ( block 2 )

ps = PredefinedSplit(folds_split)      
rfr = RandomForestRegressor( **rfr_params )

grid_params = { 'n_estimators':n_estimators }
gcv = GridSearchCV( rfr, grid_params, scoring=gini_scorer, cv=ps )

gcv.fit( dat, y )

print gcv.grid_scores_
```