# Do we One Hot Encode (create Dummy Variables) before or after Train/Test Split?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics

I've seen quite a lot of conflicting views on if one-hot encoding (dummy variable creation) should be done before/after the training/test split.

Responses seem to state that one-hot encoding before leads to "data leakage".

This example states it's industry norm to do one-hot encoding on the entire data before training/test split:

[Industry Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084770/one-hot-encoder-what-is-the-industry-norm-to-encode-before-train-split-or-after)

This example from kaggle states that it should be done after the training/test split to avoid data leakage:

[kaggle response - after split](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/getting-started/104651)

My question is the following;

1. Do we perform one-hot encoding before or after the Train/Test Split?
2. Where is the data leakage occuring in the following example?

If we take the following example, we have two columns - **web_views and website** (non-ordinal categorical feature) (assuming we are one-hot encoding across the entire column, not dropping any dummies)

Our dataframe:

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'web_views': [100,200,300,400], 
                  'website': ['Youtube','Facebook','Instagram', 'Google']})
```

## **Scenario 1: One-Hot Encoding/Dummy Variables before splitting into Train/Test**:

```
np.random.seed(123)


df_before_split = pd.concat([df.drop('website', axis = 1), pd.get_dummies(df['website'])], axis=1) 

# create your X and y dataframes
X_before_split = df_before_split.drop('web_views', axis = 1)
y_before_split = df_before_split['web_views']

# perform train test split
X_train_before_split, X_test_before_split, y_train_before_split, y_test_before_split = train_test_split(X_before_split, y_before_split, test_size = 0.20)
```

Now viewing the dataframes we have:

```
# view X train dataset (this is encoding before split)
X_train_before_split
```

and then for test

```
# View X test dataset dataset (this is encoding before split)
X_test_before_split
```

## **Scenario 2: One-Hot Encoding/Dummy Variables AFTER splitting into Train/Test**:

```
# Perform One Hot encoding after the train/test split instead

X = df.drop('web_views', axis = 1)
y = df['web_views']

# perform data split: 
np.random.seed(123)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

# perform one hot encoding on the train and test dataset datasets: 
X_train = pd.concat([X_train.drop('website', axis = 1), pd.get_dummies(X_train['website'])], axis=1)
X_test = pd.concat([X_test.drop('website', axis = 1), pd.get_dummies(X_test['website'])], axis=1)
```

Viewing the X_train and X_test dataframes:

```
# encode after train/test split - train dataframe
X_train

# encode after train/test split - test dataframe
X_test
```

## Performing Linear Regression Modelling

Now that we have split our data to demonstrate we will create a simple linear model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

**Before split linear model**

```
regressor_before_split = LinearRegression()  
regressor_before_split.fit(X_train_before_split, y_train_before_split)

y_pred_before_split = regressor_before_split.predict(X_test_before_split)
y_pred_before_split
```

**y_pred_before_split** returns a predicting value what we would expect.

**After split linear model**

```
regressor_after_split = LinearRegression()  
regressor_after_split.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_after_split = regressor_after_split.predict(X_test)
y_pred_after_split
```

### Error message from Scenario 2:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-c63978a198c8> in <module>()
      2 regressor_after_split.fit(X_train, y_train)
      3 
----> 4 y_pred_after_split = regressor_after_split.predict(X_test)
      5 y_pred_after_split

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    254             Returns predicted values.
    255         """
--> 256         return self._decision_function(X)
    257 
    258     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    239         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    240         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 241                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    242 
    243     def predict(self, X):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    138         return ret
    139     else:
--> 140         return np.dot(a, b)
    141 
    142 

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

My thoughts:

1. Encoding with dummies before splitting ensures that the test data that we pass in e.g. X_test to perform the predicitions has the same shape as the training data that the model was trained on therefore understands how to predict values when it encounters these features - unlike with encoding after splitting, since the X_test data has only one feature we are using to make predicitions with whereas the X_train has 3 features
2. Maybe I've introduced data leakage?

I'd be happy for someone to correct me if i've got things wrong or misinterpreted anything, but i'm stuck scratching me head if you encode before or after splitting!